# Laravel 5.8 UUID not auto incrementing

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using uuid for my primary key in my table but it's not auto incrementing.

This is my trait I use for uuid's as PK:

```
trait UsesUuid
{
    protected static function bootUsesUuid()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            if (!$model->getKey()) {
                $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = (string) Str::uuid();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set auto incrementing.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIncrementing()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Set primary key type to string.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKeyType()
    {
        return 'string';
    }
}
```

In my migration I do this:

```
$table->uuid('id')->primary();
```

How can I give a default value to this uuid?

my error:

> Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: According to https://dev.to/wilburpowery/easily-use-uuids-in-laravel-45be you should also add some things to your model. Have you done this?

Comment: What are you running to get the error?